# Why are my instances offset from their spawn point?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

hoping you can help shed some light on this issue.

Im using geometry nodes to instance a collection of objects on a plane.  But the instances are all offset  from the plane, rather than spawning from the points on the plane.

I've moved the objects off to the side of my scene, and the offset of the instances is the same as the distance away from the plane that my objects are (if I move the object, the instances move freely from the plane)
[image]

How do I make it so that the objects spawn from the points of the plane, instead of being based on the original object's position in space?   If i need to move my original objects i dont want all the instances flying away with them.

Each origin of the object is at the center of their respective object, and i've even Applied Location and tried Applied Location to Deltas.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you check "Reset Children" on the collection info node?

Answer (score 1):

Ticking "Reset Children" in the collection info node solved it.